# What is the plan for the US Government's Data.gov?

Tags: usa, data.gov

The US Government recently announced an intent to upgrade Data.gov.  What are the specific technical plans to do so?

Answer (score 10):

On the Data.gov team, we'll be blogging and posting here as well about some of the upcoming changes.  The intent is to have all of you give us feedback as we start to evolve ideas, rather than just seeing what happens at the end of the design process.

My blog above shows the catalog upgrade using CKAN 2.0 (it's the demonstration site, so don't worry if you see only some of the data there): http://geo.gov.ckan.org/dataset  We'll show you a demonstration shortly of the harvesting of agency JSON files as a new way to federate data to the catalog, and later redesigns of some of home page, dataset pages, and other Drupal components on the site.

We are rebuilding Data.gov from the inside out, and have spent time this last year working with the government of India, and now Canada and Ghana as well to open source the Open Government Platform as the underlying code under Data.gov.  You can find it on Github: https://github.com/opengovplatform/opengovplatform-beta/wiki

Comment: Independent of data.gov itself, how much work will be done to unify all agencies' data into that infrastructure? For example, having Bureau of Transportation Statistics at data.gov instead of its own database-backed site?

Comment: Agencies can continue to host data at their own sites, although Data.gov does provide a centralized, cloud-based hosting service. However, all agency data that is publicly accessible will need to be published at "agency.gov/data" in either a JSON file(s) or other harvestable format.

Answer (score 5):

See this blog post about their move to the CKAN platform: http://www.data.gov/blog/under-hood-open-data-engine